# why am I getting presenting nil modal view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am getting this error "Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target ."
 This is the code I have and I am trying to setup if condition is meet, it will change initial view controller.

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:( NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
 if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"logged_in"]) {


    ViewControllerOne *vc1 = [[ViewControllerOne alloc]init];
    vc1=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"vc1"];




    [self presentViewController:vc1 animated:YES completion:Nil];





} else {

    ViewControllerTwo *vc2 = [[ViewControllerTwo alloc]init];
    vc2=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"vc2"];




    [self presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:Nil];

}
// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
}
```

Comment: clean your project once and rebuild it, hope it solves your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I use is, I think you are missing the `UIWindow`:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *mainViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = mainViewController;

    return YES;
}
```

Then you can replace:

```
[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

with:

```
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"vc1"];
```

Comment: I believe so, I setup vc1 and vc2 on storyboard id.

Comment: I believe the self.stroyboard I didn't do, how do I setup that

Comment: where do I add this code? I believe I know where to add the code, but just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

You are dismissing a view controller in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. But the AppDelegate is not a view controller, so there is nothing to dismiss.

What exactly do you want to dismiss when starting the app? I suppose you just want to **present** the correct VC, not dismiss it.

Also, doing two animations in a row also normally does not work. Consider doing the first with `animated:NO` instead.

Comment: Sorry, edited the code, I accidentally added dismiss just to see what happens, same result.